# I'm trying to update a texture with glTexSubImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl

I started learning OpenGL recently and I've been messing with texture. I updated my texture using `glTexImage2D` but I've learned that it's better to use `glTexSubImage2D`, so I tried to change my code but i doesn't work.

**Working code**

```
void GLWidget::updateTextures(){

    QImage t = img.mirrored();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

**Not working code**

```
void GLWidget::updateTextures(){

    QImage t = img.mirrored();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, t.width(), t.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

All I have is a black screen.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

Here is the initialization of my texture :

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL(){

...

    LoadGLTextures();

...

}

void GLWidget::LoadGLTextures(){


    QImage t = img.mirrored();

    glGenTextures(1, &tex);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

`img` is a `QImage` variable containing the pixel data.

`glGetError()` Returns code 1281.

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return any useful information ? And why is there a literal `3` instead of a `GL_` macro as third parameter of your `glTexImage2D` call ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

glTexSubImage2D updates the content of a previously allocated texture. glTexImage2D has to be called at least once to trigger the allocation:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL(){

    //...

    QImage t = img.mirrored();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        3,
        t.width(),
        t.height(),
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        t.bits()
    );

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // ...
}
```

Update with glTexSubImage2D:

```
void GLWidget::updateTextures(){

    QImage t = img.mirrored();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexSubImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        t.width(),
        t.height(),
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        t.bits()
    );

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

**EDIT:** the problem was glTexImage2D and glTexSubImage2D were called with different image sizes, generating the error GL_INVALID_VALUE (1281, 0x501) on glTexSubImage2D call.

Comment: The size of my texture is, indeed, fixed and known. Unfortunately, I've already used glTexImage2D once, like you explained (The method in my question is "updateTexture" since I've already created it. But when I created the texture for the first time with glTexImage2D, I allocated data, not a nllptr, does it change anything ?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything. You can pass a valid pointer to initial data. Can you please edit your question with the initialization code and the result of glGetError() after the call to glTexSubImage2D?

Comment: Just to be sure, you should also call glGetError() before glTexSubImage2D to clear the error stack. Error 1281 is `GL_INVALID_VALUE`: looking the [manual](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml), it suggests the width and/or height passed to the function are inadequate. Are you sure the size of img is the same in `LoadGLTextures` and `updateTextures`?

Comment: glGetError before returns 0. img is a frame extracted from a video stream so the size doesn't change.

Comment: So I tried a few things and indeed the size when I call glTexImage2D is not registered correctly so that's were the problem is. By putting the correct size it works fine thanks. I now need to find why it's not the correct size during the first call.